# If $p \rightarrow q$ and $q \rightarrow r$, then why $(p \rightarrow (q\rightarrow r))$?

Tags: logic

I'm currently reading a proof for $\{ p \rightarrow q,  q \rightarrow r\} \vdash p \rightarrow r$.
 However, given these premises, I can't understand  how the author arrives at  ($q \rightarrow r)  \rightarrow (p \rightarrow  (q\rightarrow r))$ at a certain step in the proof.

What's the justification for this? Also, can you maybe provide the intuition behind this implication?

Comment: $a\to (p\to a)$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $(q\rightarrow r) $ is true then

i) if $p$ is true, $(p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r))$ is true (as the truth implies the truth).

ii) if $p$ is false, $(p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r))$ is true (as the false implies the truth).

Comment: Yup, you're right, I completely disregarded the  fact that $(q \rightarrow r)$ is true. Will accept your answer when the site allows me to

Answer (score 0):

As for the intuition, consider the tableau:

[image: The tableau.]

You start with $p\to q, q\to r, \lnot(p\to (q\to r))$ and end up showing that, no matter what, you get a contradiction; that is, that the tableau is closed. Thus $$p\to q, q\to r\vdash(p\to (q\to r)).$$

Comment: Typo?  Surely you meant, $\begin{array}{rl}p\to q~,~q\to r~,~\neg(p\to (q\to r))&\vdash& \bot\\\hline p\to q~,~ q\to r&\vdash& (p\to (q\to r))\end{array}$